# Watchman React Native keeps refreshing client over and over again

Tags: reactjs, react-native, watchman

- OS: Manjaro 20.1.2
- Kernel: 5.8.16-2-MANJARO
- Watchman: 20200920.192359.0 (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/watchman-bin)
- React Native: 0.63

I have an issue where, I think, Watchman keep re-crawling my project. Basically, my React Native app, on the emulator, keeps refreshing over and over again every 10 seconds or so.

In Metro I see the following over and over:

> [Fri Oct 23 2020 11:13:33.189]  BUNDLE  ./index.js
>
> [Fri Oct 23 2020 11:13:38.681]  LOG      Running "myProject" with {"rootTag":1}
>
> [Fri Oct 23 2020 11:14:09.434]  BUNDLE  ./index.js
>
> [Fri Oct 23 2020 11:14:11.666]  LOG      Running "myProject" with {"rootTag":21}

What I've tried:

Installed inotify:

```
sudo pacman -Syu

sudo pacman -S inotify-tools
```

Upped the inotify:

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman shutdown-server && sudo sysctl -p
```

Which gives me the following:

```
❯ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
999999
❯ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
999999
❯ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events
999999
```

Made it permanent in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
vm.nr_hugepages = 2048
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 999999
fs.inotify.max_queued_events = 999999
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 999999
```

Tried:

```
watchman watch-del-all

watchman shutdown-server
```

I've also tried running this clear script (slightly edited for my env):

https://gist.github.com/jesussteve/45a9251e4d1419283086379e069aed56 - Including removing the app from the client and restarting the emulator.

And I've also tried running `yarn start` and `yarn start android` inside VS Code and outside it via the terminal. I also disabled all extensions.

My project is NOT in any dropbox, google drive, cloud storage directory of any kind etc.

Not sure what else to do!

Some troubleshooting links:

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#linux-inotify-limits

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#avoiding-recrawls

https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/163

https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "emu": "./emulator.sh",
    "up": "npm-run-all -p start android",
    "start": "yarn react-native start",
    "android": "yarn react-native run-android",
    "server": "node ./server/index.js",
    "clean": "./react-native-clean.sh ./",
    "ios": "yarn react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "2.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "5.0.0",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "5.0.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-svg":"12.1.0",
    "react-native-screens":"2.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler":"1.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "@ui-kitten/metro-config": "5.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```